# Graphics, dispose before reuse?

Tags: c#, dispose, graphic

I want to know, should i dispose a Graphic object before reusing it?
meaning i replace it´s value:

graphic = "createGraphic"

something like that, should i dispose before that?

here is an example code where i use it:

```
                        gmp.DrawImage(newImage, 0, 0);
                        if (newImage.Size != panelm.Size)
                        {
                            panelm.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { panelm.Size = newImage.Size; });
                            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { this.Size = newImage.Size; });
                            gmp.Dispose();
                            gmp = panelm.CreateGraphics();
                        };
```

So, this is in a while loop, before the while, i make gmp inherit panelm.
But, i never dispose of it in the loop, i just reuse it all the time, Except, if the sizes don´t match.

Then i need to recreate it (else it´s to big/small).

But now the thing is, should i dispose before, or should i just use creategraphic?

Also, the problem here is. I can´t use, "Using" on gmp. Cause if i do, i only have 2 possibilities.

1: create it before the while loop, and reuse it until the while loop ends ( meaning, i can never change it).
2: create it inside the while loop, (meaning it will be recreated every loop which i think will be a waste).

Thanks

Comment: You should **always** dispose of objects that contain native resources. `Graphics`, `Socket`s, anything.

Comment: If a class implements IDisposable interface, you can be sure there's a reason for that. C# allows you to not care about GC, but it's a good practice to do so, especially when creating objects in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're asking if you should call `Dispose()` on it before you give it a new value?

```
Graphics gmp = panelm.CreateGraphics();
//do work
gmp.Dispose();
gmp = panelm.CreateGraphics();
```

versus

```
Graphics gmp = panelm.CreateGraphics();
//do work
gmp = panelm.CreateGraphics();
```

As good practice, you should call `Dispose()` when you're done; although it will automatically get cleaned up by the garbage collector sometime if you don't, so you're not leaking resources either way.

Comment: Yes exactly. And yeah i will dispose of it when i am done with it.
but should i dispose it there or what?
it´s the same with TCPClient, i don´t know if i should .Close before = new TCPClient().

Comment: Yep, you should dispose of it before you assign a new value to it.

Comment: Great, and why is that, would be nice to know why i shouldn´t assign before disposing, as i assign it right in the next row:)

Comment: If you don't call Dispose on it, the Graphics object would hold on to its resources for a while (until the garbage collector comes around). That means your application will use more memory than is required. If you only create one or two Graphics objects, you might not notice it, but if you call CreateGraphics too many times, the memory usage might become noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

Reference-type variables don't hold objects, but instead *identify* them; it may be helpful to think of them as object IDs.  If a call to `CreateGraphics` returns "Object #4872", then it is necessary to ensure that something will call `Dispose` on Object #4872.  If `someVariable` happens to hold "Object #4872", then saying `someVariable.Dispose` won't actually do anything to `someVariable`, but will instead call `Dispose` on object #4872.  If the code were to overwrite the variable before calling `Dispose`, it would have no way of knowing which object needed to have its `Dispose` method called.